# Render table data to pdf in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a an html form with a data table which has a pdf button on every row. I want to click that button and data for that particular row from mysql database is fetched and rendered into a table in pdf i.e. I want to render data array fetched from a table with a set id into a table in pdf. The code I wrote is rendering the first row incorrectly outside the table in pdf but all other rows correctly under their respective column (see below image)

[image]

Here is my code in **view_payment_request.php**;

```
<?php

    if
        (
            isset($_GET["pdf"]) &&
            isset($_GET['payment_request_id'])
        )
    {
        require_once 'pdf.php';
        include('database_connection.php');
        include('function.php');
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $output = '';
        $statement = $connect->prepare
            (
                "
                  SELECT
                      *
                  FROM
                      tbl_payment_request
                  WHERE
                      payment_request_id = :payment_request_id
                  LIMIT 1
                "
            )
        ;
        $statement->execute
            (
                array
                    (
                        ':payment_request_id'       =>  $_GET["payment_request_id"]
                    )
            )
        ;
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .=
                '
                    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2">Count</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">CRS/Site</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Protocol</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Budget Class</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                '
            ;

            $statement = $connect->prepare
                (
                    "
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            tbl_cost_sharing
                        WHERE
                            payment_request_id = :payment_request_id
                    "
                )
            ;
            $statement->execute
                (
                    array
                        (
                            ':payment_request_id'       =>  $_GET["payment_request_id"]
                        )
                )
            ;
            $cost_sharing_result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $count = 0;
            foreach($cost_sharing_result as $sub_row)
            {
                $count = $count + 1;
                $output .=
                    '
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$count.'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["crs_site_id"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["protocol_id"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["budget_class_id"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["cost_sharing_amount"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                    '
                ;
            }
//            Added Table Closing Tag
            $output .=
                '
                    </table>
                '
            ;
        }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $pdf = new Pdf();
        $file_name = 'PRF#'.$row["payment_request_id"].'.pdf';
        $pdf->loadHtml($output);
        $pdf->render();
        $pdf->stream($file_name, array("Attachment" => false));
    }

?>
```

Comment: can you show us an example for $output also you should finish the <table> tag

Comment: I tried to end the <table> by </table> but the results never changed

Comment: it must be </table> at the end after the last </tr>, so still post a $output

Comment: I dont know if I got well what you meant by an example of $output but from the image I have shared before, the row on the right side of table headings should appear under the headings.

Comment: html hashas a form that must be kep see https://html.com/tables/ as long as your output doesn't look that way, it will give you some unwanted result

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing rowspans from the  tags.